# How to specify a non relevant tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I recently saw a tag [link-buliding](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/link-buliding) what has been created with a spelling mistake (second "**l**" before the second "**i**").

It's not a big deal but how can I specify this tag must be replaced by the good one [link-building](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/link-building)? Can moderators do something for this? This tag will be deleted or merged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moderators can perform tag merges.  I have done so in this case because it is so straightforward.

Comment: Thanks Stephen for merging this tag.

Comment: Especially since I appear to be the one that introduced the badly spelled tag.

Comment: No problem for that.